# AWS Canvas: Lab status: failed. Credentials must be an instance of Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS canvas for learning AWS. While doing a lab session whenever I am trying to start the lab am getting this kind of error:

[image: error]

Comment: Contact your AWS Academy educator. Also, please don't post errors as screenshots, but properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: If this is regarding AWS Academy, see: https://aws.amazon.com/training/awsacademy/contact/